# In the iPhone simulator, is there a way to set a contact as owner?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, addressbook

I am doing some AddressBook testing and I am looking for a way to test if someone is the device owner. In lieu of that, in order to test on the simulator I actually have to have a device owner in the address book.

You can add contacts to the simulator address book but I couldn't find a way to make one the owner. How can you set the device owner in the iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to change the owner on the simulator as it is a feature of Mail, Contacts, and Calendars, which is not available on the simulator. 
You would normally go to Settings>[General>Siri OR Mail, Contacts, Calendars]>My Info and select a contact from there.

[image: Siri settings]

[image: Mail Settings]
Description of changing owner: 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3997414?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Even before Siri was introduced I was able to set an "owner"